# In AngularJS to display tabs using a mouse click and swipe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create tabs that will get data from an array (using ng-repeat) for a set of questions. I need to display the page to answer a question for a particular tab and again need to keep the selected answer and to traverse to the other page can keep track of answers.

And at last will be able to see the unanswered question and answer at last. What would be some code for this?

I need to use it on a laptop as well on mobile.

Comment: Have you at least tried anything? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ng-click, it is possible to keep click for laptop and (angular-touch) ng-swipe-left for tab. I have achieved the scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by *"to keep click for laptop and (angular-touch) ng-swipe-left for tab"* (seems incomprehensible)?